# How to check if a router support Bonjour protocol?

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, ios, bonjour

I am trying to print something from iPad using printer connected with WLAN. However, iPad unable to discover printer and after searching on internet, I found that iPad and other iOS devices uses AirPrint technology based on Bonjour protocol and also found that not all router support Bonjour protocol.

I searched on internet to find methodology to check if wireless router support the Bonjour protocol or not. However, I could not find a method which can be used to check wireless router for Bonjour protocol support.

Any suggestion which could help me to check that Bonjour protocol support in router will be appreciated. I have windows to computer and want to use to validate the Bonjour protocol support and do not want to install in any app on iPad.

Answer (score 4):

**Most routers should support Bonjour;**

I don't know of a way to check if a router supports Bonjour, however, it was released in 2002, so I'd expect any router released from 2005 onward is likely to support it.

**Try disabling "Airtime Fairness" on your router;**

I found that while using WiFi I could connect to the printer's web configuration pages, I was unable to find the printer on iOS and macOS devices using AirPrint.

Following other people's advice, once I disabled "AirTime Fairness" on the router, all came good.

This worked with an Epson WF-3640 and an Asus RT-AC88U (both on latest firmware).

**On ASUSWRT based Asus routers;**

To disable "AirTime Fairness", you can;

- Click “Wireless” on left
- Click “Professional” tab
- Set “Band” to “2.4GHz”
- Set “Airtime Fairness” to “Disable”
- Click “Apply”

NB: If your printer can also connect to WiFi using 5GHz, you'll need to repeat the steps above, while setting the band to 5GHz instead.

Comment: Thanks for saving me... It worked like a charm.

Comment: I was going insane trying to figure out why the printer was not discoverable while it worked perfectly when mapped by IP directly: it was the "Air Time Fairness"setting on the router! Thank you.

Comment: After 3 years of searching for problem using airplay with my Brother printer on my Asus RT-AC88U router, it is finally solved after disabling AirTime Fairness.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Any "wireless router" that doesn't have multicast-handling bugs will support Bonjour discovery among connected devices.

What we typically call a "wireless router" is like a Wi-Fi AP and 4-port Ethernet switch connected to the LAN side of a home gateway router.

Between Wi-Fi and LAN, such a "router" isn't really a router, but just an AP that bridges traffic among wireless clients and LAN devices.

Such a device doesn't have to do anything special to allow those WLAN and LAN devices to discover each other. It just has to handle multicast traffic correctly.

If your Wi-Fi AP (wireless router) isn't allowing Bonjour to work, first make sure you haven't enabled any kind of "client isolation" feature. If that's not it, troubleshoot why multicast is broken on your network. Try disabling wireless security temporarily: multicasts have to be handled differently from unicasts in WPA2, and that's often a source of bugs.

Comment: I disabled the WPA2 security but did not help. I could not any thing special in router configuration related to enable and disabling of multicast. I have router from FiberHome and it is DSL router means it is connected with server provider via dsl.